# How to use Jetpack Compose in a legacy app

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to integrate Compose in a legacy code that uses Dagger and Hilt.

These are the relevant part of the configuration:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
    id 'com.google.firebase.appdistribution'
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
}

android {

    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode versionCode
        versionName versionName

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = 11
    }

    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.2"
        kotlinCompilerVersion = kotlin_version
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = freeCompilerArgs + [
                "-P",
                "plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:liveLiteralsEnabled=false",
        ]
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
    implementation UI.composeRuntime
    implementation UI.composeUI
    implementation UI.composeMaterialIconExtended
    implementation UI.composePreview
    implementation UI.composeUiTooling
    implementation UI.composeJunit4
    implementation UI.composeActivity
    implementation UI.composeConstraintLayout
}
```

where:

```
object UI {
    const val composeUI = "androidx.compose.ui:ui:${Version.compose}"
    const val composeRuntime = "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:${Version.compose}"
    const val composeMaterial = "androidx.compose.material:material:${Version.compose}"
    const val composeMaterialIconExtended =
        "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:${Version.composeIconExtended}"
    const val composePreview = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:${Version.compose}"
    const val composeUiTooling = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:${Version.compose}"
    const val composeJunit4 = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:${Version.compose}"
    const val composeActivity = "androidx.activity:activity-compose:${Version.composeActivity}"

    object Version {
        const val compose = "1.3.3"
        const val composeActivity = "1.4.0"
        const val constraintLayout = "2.1.2"
        const val composeConstraintLayout = "1.0.0-rc02"
        const val composeIconExtended = "1.0.5"
    }
}
```

In the project build.gradle file I have:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.10'
    ext.gradle_plugin = '1.8.10'
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$gradle_plugin"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.44.2"
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.2'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appdistribution-gradle:3.2.0'

        def nav_version = "2.4.2"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

The app builds successfully but at runtime a get a crash with the error:

> ```
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method Int$class-CommonModule()I in class Lcom/my/package/di/LiveLiterals$CommonModuleKt;
> ```

where `CommonModule` is a Dagger/Hilt Module.

I have added

```
"plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:liveLiteralsEnabled=false",
```

trying to get rid of this problem but it doesn't help.

The app is modular and I have applied `Compose` only to the `app` module that contains the Android UI that is now Activities and Fragments and layout XMLs.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add this line in your `build.gradle`

```
kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = '1.3.3'
```

the latest version of `kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion` is 1.4.2.
but keep in your mind it should be compatible with your kotlin version.
please check this and sync your project again and notify me that is your problem solved?

Comment: I have it already in my gradle file. I'm using `1.4.2`

Comment: Please read my answer again

Comment: What do you mean? I have that line in my gradle file and I'm using the correct version since I'm using Kotlin `1.8.10`